# Show the normal subgroups and cosets of a dihedral group (D6)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups, cayley-table

$G=D_6$ and $H=<R^2>$. Use this Cayley table [for $D_6$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwKXe.png)

(a). Show that $H \vartriangleleft G$.

I want to show by finding out $aH=Ha$ for all $a \in G$, but then how do I proceed, it would be too tedious to check all $a$ in $D_6$, is there any way else to show it?

(b). List all cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Since I have $H=<R^2>={I,R^2,R^4}$, should be $IH,RH,R^2H.......F_6H$ and write then all out?

(c). What is the Cayley Table for $G/H$?

What should be the elements of $G/H$? Left cosets of $H$ in $G$?

Comment: Writing out all elements would not be my approach. How much do you know about $D_6$? It is generated by two elements, which have some relation between them. Using that it would become easier. After seeing this for a), I think you can find b) as well. Yes elements of $G/H$ are left cosets of $H$.

Comment: @Rico I still don't see what do you mean by relations between the two elements in $D_6$, do you mean $R$ and $F$?

Comment: I am not sure what your F and D are, but from what I can remember I would define $D_6$ as $\langle r,s \rangle$ with $r^6=1$ and $s^2=1$. Here $r$ would represent a rotation and $s$ a reflection. From your question I dont think F and R are the same elements as my s and r. However in my case I have $sr^i = r^{-i}s$. This makes everything easier.

Comment: Your $F$ and $R$ seem strange to me. Maybe you learned another way of $D_6$ that is unknown to me. In any case you should try to find some relation that lets you rewrite every element in the form $R^iF^j$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's remember that
$$D_6=\langle r,o: o^2=r^6=(or)^2=e \rangle$$
 1. All elements come in the form of $o^m r^n$, with $m=1,0$ we can check that $H$ is normal by showing that $aha^{-1}\in H$, with $a=o^m r^n$ and $h=r^{2s}$ we have 
$$aha^{-1}=o^m r^n r^{2s} r^{-n} o^{-m}=o^m r^{2s} o^{-m}$$
if $m=0$ or $s=0$ we're done as it is clearly in $H$, if $m=1$ amd s=1 we have
$$orro=or(or^{-1})^{-1}=or(or^5)^{-1}=(or)(or)^{-1}r^{-4}=r^2$$
and for $s=2$
$$or^4o=or(or^{-3})^{-1}=or(or^3)^{-1}=(or)(or)^{-1}r^{-2}=r^4$$
Which gives us that $H$ is normal.

2. The cosets will be $H$ $oH$ and $rH$ because any even power of $o$ will neutralize itself while any even power of $r$ will reduce the power within the normal subgroup by an even number because it goes through all even within it.
3. Elements in $D_6/H$ are the cosets, so we have $e$, $o$ and $r$ and $or$, which means it's order is 4 and as we have $r^2=o^2=e$ we have that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ under addition.

Comment: is $o$ my $R$ and $r$ my $F$?

Comment: I couldn't honestly make head of what your $R$ and $F$ were, I assumed you meant $R$ for rotation and $F$ for mirroring, though why you have 6 $F$ in your baffles me. In my case $r$ is rotation, $o$ is mirroring and $e$ is the unit

Comment: That is also why I wrote out the definition of the group so you could make the translation more easily.

Comment: I think we are just having different notations since my $R$ is rotation and $F$ is reflection. For the cosets, shouldn't there also be right cosets?

Comment: It is, though I saw $F_6$ and it baffled me :) Then $R=r$ and $F=o$, I hope the rest is understandable.

Comment: We have $R=r$ and  $F_i=sr^i$ in the standard notation, I believe.

Comment: If that is what he meant with it then yes it is, I find adding $F_i$ adds nothing but confusion. So here is mine!

Answer (score 0):

$H=\{id,R^2,R^4\}$ is the unique subgroup of $D_6$ having order $3$. It is a normal subgroup, because we have $R^i(R^2)R^{-1}=R^2, R^i(R^4)R^{-1}=R^4$, and $F_1R^2F_1^{-1}=R^4$, $F_2R^2F_2^{-2}=R^4$ and so on. We just can check this from the Cayley table, that $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ for all $g\in D_6$. It follows that the quotient group $D_6/H$ has order $4$. There are only two possible groups of order $4$. In this case we have $D_6/H\simeq C_2\times C_2$, the Kleinian $4$-group, because obviously $D_6/H$ has no element of order $4$.